# How can I insert text to a buffer without the trailing "nil"

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've got a function to insert the current date into my file

```
(defun insert-date ()
   (interactive)
   (insert 
        (format-time-string "%m-%d-%Y")))
```

This works for inserting the date into my current buffer, however the output is `01-24-2011nil`

How can I remove the nil from the input.

Comment: That's `insert`'s return value, and it should not occur (and doesn't in my experiments) if you evaluate it calling M-x insert-date, or M-: (insert-date). How are you calling the function?

Comment: @Ulrich - put that as an answer, get some credit.  I was going to give that same answer, but then it looks like I'm cherry picking.  :)

Comment: @Ulrich    I'm evaluating the function in a buffer using CTRL-j

Comment: @Trey: well, if you insist. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted above, `insert` returns `nil` and inserts the arguments as a side effect. Since you've declared your function `interactive`, you can call it using M-x. Even if you don't declare it interactive,  you can say `M-: (insert-date)`.

Answer (score 4):

It's the `C-j` that is inserting `nil`. The function itself as you've defined it is OK.  `C-j` in the scratch buffer is useful for debugging Lisp that you have written, but you have to remember that it will insert the return value.  If you don't want that, try `C-x C-e` instead.

Comment: thanks for the reply, this was covered in the comments above.

Comment: Actually `C-x C-e` is not covered in the comments above, the other suggestions are all to use `M-x` or `M-:`to run the command from the minibuffer.  But if you already have the command you want run in the buffer, then `C-x C-e` may be a better option, and is closer to `C-j` in the way it is used.